# Value didn't double

Tags: c#

I have error in this code. What should happen is if I have two stall in the database, the stall price must be doubled, but what happened in this code is if I have two stall in the database, the stall price isn't doubled and if I only have one stall the stall price is 0.

```
public double GetStallPrice(int commtaxno)
{
    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM contract_details WHERE comm_tax_no = " + commtaxno;
        DatabaseString myConnectionString = new DatabaseString();
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString.connect();
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = query;

        OleDbDataReader stallReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        stallReader.Read();

        while(stallReader.Read())
        {
            try
            {
                string query2 = "SELECT section_ID FROM specific_stall WHERE stall_no = '" + stallReader["stall_no"].ToString() + "'";
                OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();
                command2.Connection = connection;
                command2.CommandText = query2;

                OleDbDataReader sectionReader = command2.ExecuteReader();
                sectionReader.Read();
                sectionid = Convert.ToInt32(sectionReader["section_ID"].ToString());

                try
                {
                    string query3 = "SELECT stall_price FROM stall_sections WHERE section_ID = " + sectionid;
                    OleDbCommand command3 = new OleDbCommand();
                    command3.Connection = connection;
                    command3.CommandText = query3;

                    OleDbDataReader stallPriceReader = command3.ExecuteReader();
                    stallPriceReader.Read();
                    stall_price = Convert.ToDouble(stallPriceReader["stall_price"].ToString());
                }

                catch (Exception c)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(c.GetBaseException().ToString());
                }

            }

            catch (Exception b)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(b.GetBaseException().ToString());
            }

            sum_stall_price = sum_stall_price + stall_price;

        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(a.GetBaseException().ToString());
    }
    return sum_stall_price;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? And how it `sum_stall_price` initialised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is here:

```
stallReader.Read();
while(stallReader.Read())
```

You read first record and then read the second, without processing the first.
You have to remove first row and leave just

```
while(stallReader.Read())
```

As a side note, you should try to always use `using` syntax with classes that implement `IDisposable` interface. So, just an example:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
{
    // All the code inside
}
```

In this way you're sure that the object is properly released.

Finally: do not compose queries manually, but use parameters instead!!
Using parameters can avoid SQL injection and many headaches due to numeric (float, double, currency) and dates conversion!!